# Sticky navigation script doesn't work correctly after browser resize

Tags: jquery, html, css

i found a jQuery script for sticky navigation that i'm using on a website.

```
$(function() {

    // grab the initial top offset of the navigation 
    var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#sticky_navigation').offset().top;

    // the function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not
    var sticky_navigation = function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // the current vertical position from the top

        // if user scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top, otherwise change it back to relative
        if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) { 
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':-23, 'left':0 });
        } else {
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'top':-30 }); 
        }   
    };

    // run the function on load
    sticky_navigation();

    // and run it again every time you scroll
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        sticky_navigation();
    });
});
```

It only works cleanly if i don't resize the browser after loading the site. If i do a resize, then the script don't know the new size and the navigation bar jumps to a different position when scrolling. I tried to add a

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    sticky_navigation();
});
```

but it didn't do anything.

It shouldn't be difficult to tell the script to check the top offset after a resize happens. **But i'm not a programmer, so if you can, please give me suggestions with code examples, not just theoretical nudges.**

Hope someone can help me.

EDIT:
**Here's the jsfiddle example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/p9Lvbz68/8/

Comment: try to define sticky_navigation_offset_top  inside sticky_navigation  function not outside

Comment: I tried it like you said, and it seems to work, but the navigation now sticks to the top and does not unstick.

Comment: Guys, i don't understand why you are trying to alter the script to behave differently. Wouldn't it make more sense to just add a request as to window resize/sizechange, so the script updates the values every time some fiddly user resizes the browser? :)

Answer (score 0):

1st try to define sticky_navigation_offset_top inside sticky_navigation function not outside

2nd try to use `$(window).on('scroll resize',function() {`

so your code should be like

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // the function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not
    var sticky_navigation = function(){
        // grab the initial top offset of the navigation 
        var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#sticky_navigation').offset().top;

        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // the current vertical position from the top

        // if user scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top, otherwise change it back to relative
        if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) { 
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':-23, 'left':0 });
        } else {
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'top':-30 }); 
        }   
    };

    // run the function on load
    sticky_navigation();

    // and run it again every time you scroll
    $(window).on('scroll resize',function() {
        sticky_navigation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the navigation still remains stuck after scrolling back. The script does not remember the initial offset.

Comment: Mohamed, please test this with a small window: https://jsfiddle.net/p9Lvbz68/3/  , after that please resize the window to a high degree but don't reload/rerun - you should see the jumping of the navigation easily when you scroll down.

Comment: @sveto I tested it .. but take a look at this .. If this what you looking for?? http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/p9Lvbz68/4/   .. test it with resize too

Comment: @sveto I update your fiddle  check this https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/p9Lvbz68/6/

Comment: On the website it doesn't work. I used your Classtofixed too. I think you're forgetting that the navigation sits below the header in my version. Please use the whole code in the jsfiddle.

Comment: please use this fiddle for the experiments: http://jsfiddle.net/p9Lvbz68/3/ --because the error happens there exactly like on my webpage. I'll update the original post too.

Comment: @sveto updated with code .. http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/p9Lvbz68/7/  .. is that what you want??

Comment: No, unfortunately it's jumping right from the beginning, in ff and in chrome. Sorry, it's getting worse. :) Please test it before you comment, so we don't spam too much here - i'm starting to feel sorry for everyone that wants to read that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Is setting 'top':-23 in your CSS not messing up your maths in the if condition?  I.e. scrolltop can't be less than the offset if the offset is negative and the lowest scrolltop can be is 0? (I haven't checked if this is the actual behaviour).

Console.log(scroll_top);
Console.log(sticky_navigation_offset_top);

After the line:

var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();

Should help you to test this theory if you view the messages in the console on scrolling after resizing.

Although this wouldn't explain why it works before resize...

------- Edit ---------

On looking at your fiddle, your jump is happening because when you make something fixed you are effectively removing it from the page layout.  Inevitably your content will get shorter and the page will appear to jump.

An example of what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/snn0xj4h/.  I've added a margin to the top of your header to account for the jump (not really the right way to fix this but it might work for you in the short term).

```
    if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) { 
        $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':"-23px", 'left':0 });
        $('#header').css("margin-top", $('#sticky_navigation').height());
    } else {
        $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'top':"-30px" }); 
        $('#header').css("margin-top", 0);
    }
```

Comment: The -23 is because i have the div of the navigation bar (transparent PNG as background) overlapping the header image (background-image which is resized dynamically w- CSS depending on browser window).

Comment: mention him to notify him with your comment .. use @ and start typing his name it will appear in top left in comment just click on it

Comment: Thanks Mohamed - @sveto

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work, matter of fact - it's worse. I made 3 screenshots for you guys, so you can understand what i mean. Nr.1 is like it was before when scrolling after page load, no resizing http://i.imgur.com/DwHq7yy.jpg . Nr.2 is like it's now when scrolling normally http://i.imgur.com/2oNXPZN.jpg . Nr.3 is the main problem, when window resized before scrolling - script uses the values from before resizing http://i.imgur.com/iVmblvh.jpg

Comment: **Please note**: All images made in the state **just before** the navigation gets sticky on the top. In other words, in #2 and #3 it sticks too soon and makes the transition between header and body visible that should be covered by the navigation bar at all times.

Comment: Had one last go: https://jsfiddle.net/r5aza3bf/. This is a solution that should definitely work for your situation.

The padding of the top div should mimic the resizing of your image (assuming you've not set it as a background image)

Comment: Edit timer lapsed - continuation:

You will probably need to remove this from your CSS.  If this doesn't work, i'm out of ideas.  Good luck ;)

Comment: I guess you still don't understand what i'm trying to achieve. Because in your last example the problem is quite evident even in the jsfiddle. Just to be sure, i tried your script in the complete html, and the navigation was not even sticky anymore. Bummer. But thanks for trying nevertheless.